# ASP.NET project, failed to rebuild ignored Bin folder

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

We are applying version control (Git) to our asp.net project.

Here are our steps :

1. Create a folder as git repository, move project files into it
2. Make sure it can be build and run
3. Using `.gitignore` from Visual Studio to ignore unnecessary compiled source, `Bin` folder, etc.
4. Push the code to git remote

However, other team member failed to build and run the project after cloning this repository to local.

We found that if we copy the ignored `Bin` folder (including all `*.dll` files) to the project folder for the other team member manually, we can then build and run the project, but we thought those should be done by nuget and Visual Studio Build.

We've also tried to keep `*.dll.refresh` files but the path recorded in the files are not compatible with other team member's computer. (i.e., path `..\\..\A` might work for `C:\Users\A` but not for `C:\Users\B`)

Are we missing something to solve the collaboration problem?

Development environment:

- Windows 7
- Visual Studio CE 2015
- Asp.net (C#)

Comment: Show the relevant warnings and errors and the relevant paths from the .csproj file. Relative paths shouldn't go outside your solution directory.

Comment: @CodeCaster All the relevant warnings and errors are 
_The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?_
and `Update-Package -reinstall` solved most of the problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We normally have the issue that with ignoring packages the nuget doesn't always download all the packages back. To solve this you can try to do a `Update-Package -reinstall` inside the nuget console.

You don't need the bin folder to build the project. It only succeeds because it has already the proper .dll imported in the bin. Make sure you have all the dependencies available on the 2nd pc.

Showing the error would help for further investigation.